# puppet-common (= 3.8.7-1puppetlabs1) Installling Error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, puppet

Tried to update puppet master version and after removing previous version when I'm trying to install

> puppet-common (= 3.8.7-1puppetlabs1)

below error occuring.

```
root@puppetmaster:/home/ubuntu/puppet# apt install puppet-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 puppet-common : Depends: libaugeas-ruby but it is not installable or
                          libaugeas-ruby1.9.1 but it is not installable or
                          libaugeas-ruby1.8 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

> ```
> apt-get install ruby  
> apt-get -f install
> ```

and

> sudo apt-get install libaugeas-ruby

didn't work as gave in other solutions.

please do let me know if any other details needed.

Comment: Are you using the official repos from Puppet?

Comment: did you do a `sudo apt-get update` before installing puppet-common?

Comment: @andrewleung yes , tried that too.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the command prompt, you are using Ubuntu.  Puppet isn't compatible with all versions of Ubuntu.  I was getting the same error messages on Ubuntu 16.06 for the same version of Puppet (3.8.7-1).  I tried a million things till I realized it was OS version to Puppet version match.

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/install_debian_ubuntu.html

If you install a version of puppet supported by the OS you are using.  It should install.  Without knowing what version of Ubuntu you are on, it is possible this isn't the problem, but if so, you should be in good shape.  Links below if you are on 16.04:

http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-puppet-on-ubuntu-16-04.html

Answer (score 1):

Your mileage may vary but the only way I could get around this problem was deleting all the puppet related `.list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Files were

```
puppetlabs.list
puppetlabs-pc1.list
puppet.list
```

Once that was done, I could run `apt-get install puppet` and the command worked just fine.